# .htaccess rewritecond [or]

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ./ext/.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^user_id=.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^customer_id=.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/404.php
```

I want if isset user_id OR customer_id on cookie, It will pass. But this doesn't work.

Comment: Remove the NOTs, i.e. remove the `!`-s

Comment: If I delete "!" symbol, It redirect to 404. If not isset, It should be 404.

Comment: That is not what you said in the accompanying text. But I thing, what you want, is to show 404 is user_id is not set **and** customer_id is not set. If so you just need to remove the [OR] so it becomes an and.

Comment: If isset user_id **OR** customer_id, It will **pass**

Comment: If `isset user_id OR customer_id`, It must **not** apply the 404 rule. So to apply the 404 rule you need the condition: `NOT(isset user_id OR customer_id)` which can be transformed into `NOT(isset user_id) AND NOT(customer_id)`.

Comment: :) php ex; `<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) OR isset($_COOKIE['customer_id'])) { ... } else header("Location:404.php");`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22269/discussion-between-arda-tunuz-and-gerben)